# Django Pyhton: Infinit Scroll feed

Tags: python, django

I'am working on a Social Media Website, I use Django, Python.

I would like to make an Infinit Scroll Paginator to have a User-Friendly Surf experience.

For now it shows a Select Bar at the end, f.e. 1, 2, 3, Last.

How to make an Infinit Scroll Paginator where it laods when you scroll to the end?

feed.html

```
    {% if posts.has_other_pages %}

  {% if posts.has_previous %}
    <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page=1">First</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{posts.previous_page_number}}">Previous</a>
  {% endif %}

  {% for num in posts.paginator.page_range %}
    {% if posts.number == num %}
      <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="?page={{num}}">{{num}}</a>
    {% elif num > posts.number|add:'-3' and num < posts.number|add:'3' %}
    <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{num}}">{{num}}</a>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% if posts.has_next %}
    <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{posts.next_page_number}}">Load more Shots</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{posts.paginator.num_pages}}">Last</a>
  {% endif %}

{% endif %}
```

views.py

```
    @login_required
def posts_of_following_profiles(request):

profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
users = [user for user in profile.following.all()]
posts = []
qs = None
for u in users:
    p = Profile.objects.get(user=u)
    p_posts = p.user.post_set.all()
    posts.append(p_posts)
my_posts = profile.profile_posts()
posts.append(my_posts)
if len(posts)>0:
    qs = sorted(chain(*posts), reverse=True, key=lambda obj:obj.date_posted)

paginator = Paginator(qs, 6)
page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    posts_list = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    posts_list = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    posts_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render(request,'blog/feeds.html',{'profile':profile,'posts':posts_list})
```

I am new to coding, i would love some request.

Comment: Did you find the answer below helpful?

Comment: Well I tried to implement it to my code, but it didn't worked, there was an error code. What code could i give you to help me implement it?

Comment: Please share the error code you received.  The more, the better, but be sure to remove anything that displays sensitive info (passwords, tokens, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly complex piece to set up if you are new to coding.  I will do my best to provide you with an approach that will get you going.

First, your terminology is accurate.  You're looking to create infinite scrolling.  This will require the use of Ajax (the more complicated piece to the puzzle).

1. You should install Jquery (Ajax) by referencing the script from within your template.  There are other ways too, but this is a quick and simple approach:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
```

2. Create your view.  THe goal here is to serve up your paginated data in JSON.

First, import Paginator (if you haven't) and JSONResponse in your views.py:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.http import JsonResponse
```

Then write the function to fetch the paginated data. SOmething like this:

```
def fetch_paginated_data(request):
    requested_page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    all_items = yourModel.objects.all()
    paginated_items = Paginator(all_items, 25)  # Display 25 items per page

    try:
        items_on_page = paginated_items.page(requested_page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        items_on_page = paginated_items.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        items_on_page = paginated_items.page(paginated_items.num_pages)

    formatted_data = []
    for item in items_on_page:
        formatted_data.append({
            'attribute1': item.attribute1,
            'attribute2': item.attribute2,
            # Add additional attributes as needed
        })

    return JsonResponse(formatted_data, safe=False)
```

3. In your template, add a DIV tage so the fetched results can be displayed:

```
<div id="results-container">
    
</div>
```

4. In your template, at the end of the document and just before your closing  tag, pu the script in place:

```
<script>
    let currentPage = 1;  // Start from the first page
    const isLoading = false;

    function loadMoreResults() {
        if (isLoading) {
            return;
        }
        isLoading = true;
        currentPage += 1;
        $.getJSON("{% url 'get_paginated_data' %}", {'page': currentPage}, function(data) {
            for (const item of data) {
                // Update this line to match the HTML structure of your results
                const newItemHTML = `<div>${item.field1} - ${item.field2}</div>`;
                $('#results-container').append(newItemHTML);
            }
            isLoading = false;
        });
    }

    // Check if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
            loadMoreResults();
        }
    });
</script>
```

If you already are starting to put your scripts into a standalone static javascript file, then you can add the above script to a separate file and then include it in your template, like so...

```
<script src="{% static 'your/path/to/the/infinite_scroll.js' %}"></script>
```

THis should get you going.

Comment: I also recommend you remove your decorator(s) and start simple to get things working.  Also, it would be helpful to really see your full code, imports, and errors.  Thanks :-)